Merge [poem] into [poetry]?
I propose merging the tag poem (4 Qs) into poetry (48 Qs) (thereby getting rid of the poem tag).  Again, this seems about as obvious as it gets.  I'm mostly just posting this for the record.
I guess it wouldn't hurt to create a poem -> poetry synonym too, although I don't think it will get used much.
The four questions tagged poem are:

Is this a valid riddle in Mandarin?
this mughal jade cup, it's "瓜瓣瓢" or "瓜辨瓢"?
Ten obligations in 三字经
Chinese Poem Crossword Puzzle

The forty-eight questions tagged poetry are:

Which Qing Dynasty Poem/Prose is this?
translation of text and seals on painting (Poet identified: Pu Ru 溥儒)
Is there any comprehensive English-language source on Classical Chinese poetic metre?
Ten obligations in 三字经
Tone 平仄 of the 5th character in a seven-character jueju 七絕
Meaning of 纷纷 (fēnfēn) referred to 雨 (yǔ)
Does anyone know this Chinese poem?
木兰辞 original poem
Names for forms of ancient poetry
How to interpret the oracle poem (諸葛武侯乩文)?
What does this seal stamp on Chinese painting mean?
How would you interpret: "你的美如日; 你的智若猫头鹰"?
(Well-known) poem request: the wonder/beauty of nature/world/universe
How to identify rhymes in a Tang poem?
Poem for Calligraphy Art
Poem "口占" by 區越
Pronunciation of Tang Dynasty Poetry
Poetry that deals with wanting to be rescued?
What does 荠麦之茂，荠麦之有 in 《猗兰操》 mean? 韩愈《猗兰操》“荠麦之茂，荠麦之有”一句作何解释？
Can someone please tell me what this poem means?
Did 李白 and 杜甫 popularize/standardize any 方言?
synonyms/phrases/poems related to: 情深恭敬少
What distinguishes modern poetry from prose?
Tao Yuanming Poem
Is Regulated Verse Used In Modern-Language Poetry?
Original Chinese version of the mango poem
"There was no attitude of poverty in his poetry" 絶無窮態
Poems about parents love and care for children
Dizi poem on my dizi flute please
Simple poetry for beginners
Rhyme and tones
What does 惟覺 mean here?
What do the Symbols ◒ and ◓ Signify In Old Chinese Poetry Books?
What does the phrase "足矣" mean?
Why Have Modern *duilian*'s become 成语+3 Random Characters?
What is the Old Chinese Pronunciation for the Character 兮?
How Should I Pronounce the Character 說 In This Lyric?
How Does One Pronounce/Define the *Chinese* Character 𦨻
张九龄《感遇》“奈何阻重深”句解／Translation of a sentence in one of Zhang Jiuling's poems
Help translating 爱人跟人走
Could someone translate text carved on my flute?
Using 變音 when reading Classical Chinese poetry in Cantonese
Where can I find Cantonese poetry?
Poetic two-character words of the form: Verb + Natural Noun?
Character layout in calligraphy e.g. with respect to a quotation from Confucius
What are the rules of writing a 对联 (chinese couplet)?
What are the different kinds of poems in Chinese?
Are there poems in Chinese that rhyme?


It looks safe to merge. Creating a synonym might be useful if [tag:poem] gets re-created frequently.
